# Powershell Works Local but Intune Gives Error

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am running the below code and will work without issue locally in Powershell. When I try to push to systems in Intune Powershell Scripts it gives me a failure. When I setup a log it states the location does not exist. I assume there is a format issue but can't seem to find any.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\log.txt"
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "RestartApps" -PropertyType 'DWORD' -Value 1
```

This should create a DWORD in registry and set its value to 1. Really a basic script.

Comment: hkey_current_user is different for every user.  So if the script runs as the system user, only the system account gets changed.

Comment: If Admin change colon to dollar sign.  Also need two backslashes at beginning of path : New-ItemProperty -Path "\\HKCU$\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "RestartApps" -PropertyType 'DWORD' -Value 1

Comment: @jdweng this is not correct. Launchpad72 are you running the script as the logged on user?

Comment: No, was not selecting the "Run this script using the logged on credentials" option. Once I selected that and pushed it again finally worked and I am getting successful status. Thanks for all who responded and for the help with getting a solution.